# How can I create a WPF DataGridView that Displays child rows (from child tables) inside parent rows?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, datagrid, devexpress-wpf

I have SQL Server Database Named **EmployeesDB** that contains 4 Tables as following:

1. **Employees** Table which is the Parent Table in this Example.
2. **EmployeesContacts** Table Which is the Child Table of Employees holding employee Telephone Numbers because most of the Employees have more than One Telephone Numbers.
3. **EmployeesLanguages** Table Which is the Child Table of Employees holding The Languages of the Employees and their Ability to Talk, Read and Write in those languages.
4. **EmployeesDuties** Table Which is the Child Table of Employees holding the Duties of all the Employees in the Company.
   Here is the Database diagram:
   [image]

And Here is the Database Script

```
USE [EmployeesDB]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Employees] ******/

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employees](
    [EmployeeID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Age] [int] NULL,
    [Gender] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Employees] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [EmployeeID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[EmployeesContacts]  ******/

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmployeesContacts](
    [EmployeeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Telephone] [nvarchar](12) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_EmployeesContacts] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Telephone] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[EmployeesDuties] ******/

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmployeesDuties](
    [EmployeeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeDutyID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Duty] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_EmployeesDuties] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [EmployeeDutyID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[EmployeesLanguages] ******/

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmployeesLanguages](
    [EmployeeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeLanguageID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LanguageName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [TalkingAbility] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [ReadingAbility] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [WritingAbility] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_EmployeesLanguages] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [EmployeeLanguageID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeesContacts]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_EmployeesContacts_Employees] FOREIGN KEY([EmployeeID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Employees] ([EmployeeID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeesContacts] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_EmployeesContacts_Employees]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeesDuties]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_EmployeesDuties_Employees] FOREIGN KEY([EmployeeID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Employees] ([EmployeeID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeesDuties] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_EmployeesDuties_Employees]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeesLanguages]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_EmployeesLanguages_Employees] FOREIGN KEY([EmployeeID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Employees] ([EmployeeID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeesLanguages] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_EmployeesLanguages_Employees]
GO
```

*And for XAML and C# it is just a Window with WPF DataGridView*

The Impossible thing to me Came when I turned to the UI of which I wanted the whole Data to appear in One DataGridView so that I take Advantages of the Features of DataGridView like Filter, Sort, Search  e.t.c.

Here is an Example of the View I Wanted which All The Rows are in Expanded Mode:
[image]

And Here is the Description of which table the Columns Belong to:
[image]

The Behaviours and Features  I wanted are:

1. To Show “Click To Add New Row” at the End of each Sub-Rows and at The End of Parent Rows like in the pictures above.
2. When I Filter for Example Employees by Duty “Advertiser”, the Filter to Show full Data with All Sub-Rows like in the Picture below (Filtered by Duties Column).

Here is an Image of How The DatagridView looks when Filtered
[image]

With all my efforts I searched google for anything similar and found Nothing, Tried SQL Server View but with no success … I will really appreciate any help in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one
XAML:

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CvsKey">
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Employee"/>
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
        
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="dataGrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}" IsReadOnly="True" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed"
                          
                  CanUserAddRows="True">

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding EmployeeID}" Header="EmployeeID"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FirstName}" Header="FirstName"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding LastName}" Header="LastName"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Age}" Header="Age"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Gender}" Header="Gender"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Email}" Header="Email"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Contects"  Width="75">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HeadersVisibility="None">
                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*">
                                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Telephone}"/>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                </DataGrid.Columns>
                            </DataGrid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Duties"  Width="75">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Duties}" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HeadersVisibility="None">
                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*">
                                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Duty}"/>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                </DataGrid.Columns>
                            </DataGrid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Languages"  Width="75">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Languages}" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HeadersVisibility="None">
                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*">
                                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LanguageName}"/>
                                                
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                </DataGrid.Columns>
                            </DataGrid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>

        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

CODE BEHIND:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private EmployeeViewModel _viewModel;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _viewModel = new EmployeeViewModel();
            DataContext = _viewModel;
        }
    }

    public class EmployeeViewModel
    {
        private readonly EmployeeDbContext _context;

        public EmployeeViewModel()
        {


            using (var context = new EmployeeDbContext())
            {
                Employees = context.Employees
                       .Include(e => e.Duties)
                    .Include(e => e.Contacts)

                    .Include(e => e.Languages)
                    .ToList();


            }

        }


        public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; } = new List<Employee>();

        public void SaveChanges()
        {
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        // Add methods for CRUD operations as needed
    }
  
    public class EmployeeDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
        public DbSet<EmployeesContact> EmployeesContacts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<EmployeesDuty> EmployeesDuties { get; set; }
        public DbSet<EmployeesLanguage> EmployeesLanguages { get; set; }




        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            // Configure your database connection here
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=(localdb)\\ProjectModels;Initial Catalog=EmployeesDB;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;Trust Server Certificate=False;Application Intent=ReadWrite;Multi Subnet Failover=False");

        }
    }
    public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<EmployeesContact> Contacts { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<EmployeesDuty> Duties { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<EmployeesLanguage> Languages { get; set; }
    }

    public class EmployeesContact
    {
        [Key] // Define TelephoneID as the primary key
        public int TelephoneID { get; set; }

        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string Telephone { get; set; }

        // Other properties and relationships
    }

    public class EmployeesDuty
    {
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        [Key]
        public int EmployeeDutyID { get; set; }
        public string Duty { get; set; }
    }

    public class EmployeesLanguage
    {
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        [Key]
        public int EmployeeLanguageID { get; set; }
        public string LanguageName { get; set; }
        public string TalkingAbility { get; set; }
        public string ReadingAbility { get; set; }
        public string WritingAbility { get; set; }
    }
}
```

RESULT:
[image]